# Conditional Probability (What is the probability that such a is a guitarist?)

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following probability question. 
"The city of Berlin is hosting the YR-Compose Festival (YRCF), a competition for young music composers. Among the participants, $50\%$ plays piano, $30\%$ violin and the remaining $20\%$ plays guitar. Only $10\%$ of the pianists and $10\%$ of the guitarists take part to YRCF for the first time. On the other hand, $30\%$ of the violinists are at their first experience with YRCF. Knowing that the first person who plays at the competition is someone who never participated to YRCF before, what is the probability that such a person is a guitarist?"

I have tried using the Bayes Theorem.
$P(C) = 100 \%$. Containing all artist.

$50 \%$ : Piano

$30 \%$ : Violin

$20 \%$ : Guitar

$P(B) = 50 \%$. Containg all firsttime artists.

$10 \%$ : Piano

$10 \%$ : Guitarist

$30 \%$ : Violinist

Using the Theorem: 
$P(R | D) = P(D | R) \times P(R) / P(D) $

$P(R) = 30 \%$. Firsttime Guitarists. 
$P(D| R) = 20 \%$. All Guitarists.

But then I am stuck calculating $P(D)$.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean only $10\color{red}{\%}$ of the pianists take part in the festival for the first time?

Comment: Yes. 10 % of the pianists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P(G)$ be the probability that the participant plays guitar; let $P(P)$ be the probability that the participant plays piano; let $P(V)$ be the probability that the participant plays violin.  We are given
\begin{align*}
P(G) & = 0.2\\
P(P) & = 0.5\\
P(V) & = 0.3
\end{align*}
Let $P(N)$ be the probability that a participant is a newcomer. We are given the conditional probabilities
\begin{align*}
P(N \mid G) & = 0.1\\
P(N \mid P) & = 0.1\\
P(N \mid V) & = 0.3
\end{align*}
The probability that the participant is a newcomer is
\begin{align*} 
P(N) & = P(G)P(N \mid G) + P(P)P(N \mid P) + P(V)P(N \mid V)\\
     & = (0.2)(0.1) + (0.5)(0.1) + (0.3)(0.3)\\
     & = 0.02 + 0.05 + 0.09\\ 
     & = 0.16
\end{align*}
If the performance slots at the competition are randomly assigned, the probability that the first newcomer to play at the festival is a guitarist is 
$$P(G \mid N) = \frac{P(G \cap N)}{P(N)} = \frac{P(G)P(N \mid G)}{P(N)} = \frac{(0.2)(0.1)}{P(N)} = \frac{0.02}{0.16} = 0.125$$
where we have solved the equation for the conditional probability that a participant is a newcomer given that she or he is a guitarist 
$$P(N \mid G) = \frac{P(G \cap N)}{P(G)}$$
to solve for 
$$P(G \cap N) = P(G)P(N \mid G)$$

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to get you started:

Of the total at the YRCF, $5\%$ are first timers as pianists ($10\%$ of $50\%$).
$2\%$ are first timers as guitarists.  $9\%$ are first timers as violinists.

So altogether $16\%$ of participants are first timers.